# Query Params get removed from react route when click on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am facing an issue in react js, there is the route to the page e.g https://localhost:3000/profile?abc=123, the URL is browsed successfully but the issue is when I click on the button (I call API on click of this button using Axios) in my website then the query params in the URL gets removed automatically like this,
https://localhost:3000/profile. I have debugged, and the params are removed when the Axios call is initiated. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: We can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see. Can you edit the post to include a [mcve] for the relevant code you are working with and have an issue using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. It turned out that I was using `<Link to='' />`. Changing it to `<Button />` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well. The problem was with React calling another method in the background, and this would reroute without the query params. This is an issue with the default methods associated with HTML elements. See [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-preventdefault/) for more info.

To fix, call the event's `preventHandler()` in the `onClick` handler of the button, after performing whatever action you need. In my case it was:

```
const keyDownHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      // do something
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };
```